# Problem with props vue js.The second element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I add two props components, but the first component works and the second one doesn't. What might be the problem. VUE CLI. In the future I need to pass more than 10 components. I will be very grateful to anyone who will help
Main component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <app-select class="select"></app-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Select from './components/Select.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    appSelect: Select
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.select {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}


</style>
```

Two component:

```
<template>
    <div id="main">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <slot>
            <p class="article">{{ mainArticle }}</p>
            <hr>
        
            <hr>
            <p class="price pol">{{ firstPLan }}</p> 
        </slot>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {

        props: {
            mainArticle: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Choose your SIMM'
            },
            firstPlan: {
                default: '2GB'
            }

        } 
    }
        
</script>
```

Screen problem:

[image]

Comment: Typo: `{{ firstPLan }}` vs `firstPlan`.

Comment: What? I dont understand

Comment: Really? You have a typo in your code, that's why it doesn't work. To make it as clear as possible: `{{ firstPLan }}` has an uppercase `L` while your prop `firstPlan` has a lowercase `l`

Comment: Thanks you! I really idiot..

Comment: @TIRPROJECT You can add this typo error as the answer.